# Typed integer constant in OCaml

Tags: type-conversion, ocaml, type-inference

Lets say you had some code like this

```
type foo_t = int64 

let do_something_with_foo (f : foo_t) = (* left to your imagination *)
```

And you wanted to call it with a constant "foo", like this:

```
do_something_with_foo 99
```

How do you convince the compiler/interpreter that your constant 99 is actually a `foo_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `do_something_with_foo 99L`.
The constant `99` has type `int`, `99L` has type `int64`.

This has nothing to do with the type alias `foo_t = int64`. As long as the definition of `foo_t` is visible (i.e. not masked by the signature of a containing module), any value of type `int64` also has type `foo_t` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

L letter matters.

```
# 99L;;
- : int64 = 99L
# 99l;;
- : int32 = 99l
# 99;;
- : int = 99
```